# How do you move elements within an array if you only have remove/insert commands?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, cocoa, nstableview

Suppose that you have the following array:

```
oldArray = ['d','e','f','i','j'];
```

and you want to make it into this new array:

```
newArray = ['d','j','f','i','e'];
```

As you may have noticed, `j` and `e` were interchanged.

But to do this you have to transform the array by just using a sequence of delete-insert command pair. That is

```
deleteInsert(array,i,j) = {
    delete the element at index i,
    move all elements in indexes after i downwards,
    and finally insert the element at index j
}
```

How do you approach this problem?

(as a background information, I am trying to get Cocoa's `NSTableView` class to update and animate correctly by moving rows within the table view).

Comment: "if you only have remove/insert commands?" Is this a condition that you are imposing?

Comment: @mikeD as per the background info, this is a condition of `NSTableView` class.

Answer (score 0):

1.Save and delete you moving element.
 2. Then shift all afterwards elements to the right till index of moving element destination. a.Save one of them. b.Remove it. c.Insert it to index which is less by 1. d. Continue until you free moving element destination index. 
 3.Insert your moving element in the currently free index.

Answer (score 0):

To exchange item `i` with item `j`:

1. Make sure `i < j` (if `i > j`, then swap (the values of variables) `i` and `j`; if `i = j`, then just return).
2. `deleteInsert(array, j, i)`
3. `deleteInsert(array, i + 1, j)`